# How to count items and put in a property with hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, count

I need to map a property of my class with a count query using hibernate. 
I have a class like this:

```
public class Surveys{
    private int completedSurveys;

    public int getCompletedSurveys{
        return completedSurveys;
    }

    public void setCompletedSurveys(int completedSurveys){
        this.completedSurveys = completedSurveys;
    }
}
```

And I need to make a count like this in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys WHERE status = 'completed'
```

and put in the property completedSurveys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an ORM. It allows you to map an instance of Survey to a row in the Surveys table. The number of completed surveys doesn't sound like a property of a Survey to me.

I would just use a service to perform the count as required using HQL rather than trying to use Hibernate to map the property. Then set the result on an object which encapsulates information about the surveys completed rather than an individual instance of a survey.

Comment: The real name of the class is not survey, I use it only for the example, the real name is quota.